# Native Android Application for website without WebView

Tags: android, web, mobile

I need to build a Native Android Application for a Website that I have successfully developed. How do I go about this without using the webView. Someone talked about REST API But I don't just know how to go about it.

Although I have the Application in webView Version already but it is just still as the normal website mobile view. No Interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is `REST API`. Here is a good example.

[How to create REST API for Android app using PHP, Slim and MySQL](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically schema should looks like backend(all your data) - Rest Api (you must provide interface to your backend data with CRUD operation like PUT-DELETE-UPDATE-RETREIVE) - users for your Rest Api (mobile apps that would call this api to use data from backend)

For backend look at this tutorial to start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkKcdK1u95s&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn

For android app you should use Retrofit2 to facilitate RestApi calls.